# Execution of NEWSEQUENTIALID inside T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if someone knows how the [`NEWSEQUENTIALID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) gets executed.

I mean does it run from the SQL Server engine or is it being evaluated from the client database driver?

Also considering that the internal Win32 implementation, this function call will generate a sequential ID from any thread if I recall correctly.

Comment: The whole point is to generate sequential IDs, which needs them to all be generated by the same machine. Why would you suspect the client would be involved?

Comment: They are generated on the server, as it is a server-side TSQL expression

Answer (score 4):

As `NEWSEQUENTIALID` can only be used as an expression in a `DEFAULT` constraint, it has nothing to do with the client, the client does not have to know about it.

A new ID will only be generated (the function will only be invoked) when the column with that `DEFAULT` constraint is not listed in an `INSERT` statement or in the `VALUES` list the keyword `DEFAULT` is used.

The key sentences in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are:

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer *since Windows was started*. After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique.

> NEWSEQUENTIALID() can only be used with DEFAULT constraints on table columns of type uniqueidentifier.